# Continuous marquee text using jquery

Tags: jquery, marquee

I am having the list items and the list items needs to be like marqueed using jQuery.

How?

Comment: Bringing back the marquee. Awesome. Whack some jquery blink functionality in as well ;)

Comment: That's uber 90s. Are you sure you can convince 'them' otherwise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check this : http://wordcrowd.org/index.php?title=Rotating_marquee_with_jQuery_Cycle

jquery cycle plugin http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/

Example :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('#marquee').cycle({ 
      fx: 'fade', 
      pause: 1 
    });
  }); 
</script>
```

Comment: with out the plugin can't we do?

Comment: i think for that you have to go for pure javascript

Answer (score 4):

Here check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/jithil89/BNBB6/

I have this example, wherein the text is continuously scrolling and pauses only on hover over the text.

Code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

//this is the useful function to scroll a text inside an element...

function startScrolling(scroller_obj, velocity, start_from) {
    //bind animation  inside the scroller element
    scroller_obj.bind('marquee', function (event, c) {
        //text to scroll
        var ob = $(this);
        //scroller width
        var sw = parseInt(ob.parent().width());
        //text width
        var tw = parseInt(ob.width());
        //text left position relative to the offset parent
        var tl = parseInt(ob.position().left);
        //velocity converted to calculate duration
        var v = velocity > 0 && velocity < 100 ? (100 - velocity) * 1000 : 5000;
        //same velocity for different text's length in relation with duration
        var dr = (v * tw / sw) + v;
        //is it scrolling from right or left?
        switch (start_from) {
            case 'right':
                //is it the first time?
                if (typeof c == 'undefined') {
                    //if yes, start from the absolute right
                    ob.css({
                        left: sw
                    });
                    sw = -tw;
                } else {
                    //else calculate destination position
                    sw = tl - (tw + sw);
                };
                break;
            default:
                if (typeof c == 'undefined') {
                    //start from the absolute left
                    ob.css({
                        left: -tw
                    });
                } else {
                    //else calculate destination position
                    sw += tl + tw;
                };
        }
        //attach animation to scroller element and start it by a trigger
        ob.animate({
            left: sw
        }, {
            duration: dr,
            easing: 'linear',
            complete: function () {
                ob.trigger('marquee');
            },
            step: function () {
                //check if scroller limits are reached
                if (start_from == 'right') {
                    if (parseInt(ob.position().left) < -parseInt(ob.width())) {
                        //we need to stop and restart animation
                        ob.stop();
                        ob.trigger('marquee');
                    };
                } else {
                    if (parseInt(ob.position().left) > parseInt(ob.parent().width())) {
                        ob.stop();
                        ob.trigger('marquee');
                    };
                };
            }
        });
    }).trigger('marquee');
    //pause scrolling animation on mouse over
    scroller_obj.mouseover(function () {
        $(this).stop();
    });
    //resume scrolling animation on mouse out
    scroller_obj.mouseout(function () {
        $(this).trigger('marquee', ['resume']);
    });
};

//the main app starts here...

//change the cursor type for each scroller
$('.scroller').css("cursor", "pointer");

//settings to pass to function
var scroller = $('.scrollingtext'); // element(s) to scroll
var scrolling_velocity = 80; // 1-99
var scrolling_from = 'right'; // 'right' or 'left'

//call the function and start to scroll..
startScrolling(scroller, scrolling_velocity, scrolling_from);

});
```