# jQuery - animate text to slide from left to right while staying always visible

Tags: jquery, css, animation

For a mobile version of my website i need to keep a nice styles from PC version. However PC version contains pretty long strings that wrap on 2 or 3 lines on a mobile and leads to weird results. What i want to achieve is to slide text to the left until last letter will be shown and then start animation again, below is an example:

```
test string: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

| Lorem ipsum dolor sit am |   //animation start
| amet, consectetur adipis |   //50% animation
| ectetur adipiscing elit. |   //animation end
| Lorem ipsum dolor sit am |   //animation starts again
----------------------------
| adipiscing elit.         |   //unwanted behaviour
```

So far from what I know about jQuery, I thought this could be done by animating `padding-right`, however according to my markup with `white-space: nowrap` padding is being ignored.

[jsfiddle markup](http://jsfiddle.net/y69446ps/1/)

Code sample:

```
<div>
    <div class="text_wrapper">
        <span class="text_overflow">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce malesuada feugiat odio rhoncus dapibus.</span>
    </div>
</div>

.text_wrapper{
    width: 100px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.text_overflow {
    word-wrap: none;
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the [various marquee jQuery plugins](https://plugins.jquery.com/tag/marquee/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/y69446ps/2/)**

Well the below function written for scrolling was originally taken from **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17040681/2065039)** and it did a trick to `scroll` your text:

```js
 //this is the useful function to scroll a text inside an element...
  function startScrolling(scroller_obj, velocity, start_from) {
        //bind animation  inside the scroller element
        scroller_obj.bind('marquee', function (event, c) {
            //text to scroll
            var ob = $(this);
            //scroller width
            var sw = parseInt(ob.closest('.text_wrapper').width());
            //text width
            var tw = parseInt(ob.width());
            //text left position relative to the offset parent
            var tl = parseInt(ob.position().left);
            //velocity converted to calculate duration
            var v = velocity > 0 && velocity < 100 ? (100 - velocity) * 1000 : 5000;
            //same velocity for different text's length in relation with duration
            var dr = (v * tw / sw) + v;
            //is it scrolling from right or left?
            switch (start_from) {
                case 'right':
                    console.log('here')
                    //is it the first time?
                    if (typeof c == 'undefined') {
                        //if yes, start from the absolute right
                        ob.css({
                            left: sw
                        });
                        sw = -tw;
                    } else {
                        //else calculate destination position
                        sw = tl - (tw + sw);
                    };
                    break;
                default:
                    if (typeof c == 'undefined') {
                        //start from the absolute left
                        ob.css({
                            left: -tw
                        });
                    } else {
                        //else calculate destination position
                        sw += tl + tw;
                    };
            }
            //attach animation to scroller element and start it by a trigger
            ob.animate({
                left: sw
            }, {
                duration: dr,
                easing: 'linear',
                complete: function () {
                    ob.trigger('marquee');
                },
                step: function () {
                    //check if scroller limits are reached
                    if (start_from == 'right') {
                        if (parseInt(ob.position().left) < -parseInt(ob.width())) {
                            //we need to stop and restart animation
                            ob.stop();
                            ob.trigger('marquee');
                        };
                    } else {
                        if (parseInt(ob.position().left) > parseInt(ob.parent().width())) {
                            ob.stop();
                            ob.trigger('marquee');
                        };
                    };
                }
            });
        }).trigger('marquee');
        //pause scrolling animation on mouse over
        scroller_obj.mouseover(function () {
            $(this).stop();
        });
        //resume scrolling animation on mouse out
        scroller_obj.mouseout(function () {
            $(this).trigger('marquee', ['resume']);
        });
};

//and now the real function with the condition to make your `text scroll`

$(function() {
        $('.text_wrapper').each(function(i, obj) {
            if ($(this).find('.text_overflow').width() > $(this).width()) {
                //settings to pass to function
       var scroller = $(this).find('.text_overflow'); // element(s) to scroll
       var scrolling_velocity = 95; // 1-99
       var scrolling_from = 'right'; // 'right' or 'left'
       //call the function and start to scroll..
       startScrolling(scroller, scrolling_velocity, scrolling_from);
            }
        });
});
```

```css
.text_wrapper{
    width: 100px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.text_overflow {
    word-wrap: none;
    position:relative; /*add this property to the scrolling texts*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div class="text_wrapper">
        <span class="text_overflow">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce malesuada feugiat odio rhoncus dapibus.</span>
    </div>
    <div class="text_wrapper">
        <span class="text_overflow">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce malesuada feugiat odio rhoncus dapibus. Phasellus id ex ac leo gravida.</span>
    </div>
    <div class="text_wrapper">
        <span class="text_overflow">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Seems pretty cool. WIll try to mess up with this code to achieve exactly what I wanted to

Comment: sure.. :) Hope you'll mark it as answer if it is what you need.. :)

Comment: Awesome function. I was able to adjust it to fit my needs and it behaves like a charm! In case you wonder what i wanted it to look like, here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/y69446ps/4/). Modified code by removing unnecessary variables and checks to make it lightweight

Comment: Yea.. Thanks to original author of the answer.. :)